# How do I enable strict mode in SQLite 3.31.1?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to enable strict mode to `require a datatype on every table column and enforce those types.` as per [this page](https://sqlite.org/src/wiki?name=StrictMode).

```
$ sqlite3 ./a_new_database.sqlite
SQLite version 3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> PRAGMA strict=ON;
sqlite> CREATE TABLE yay ( col1 TEXT, col2 INT );
sqlite> INSERT INTO yay ( col1, col2 ) VALUES ("this works", "this is the wrong type");
sqlite> SELECT * from yay;
this works|this is the wrong type
sqlite> 
$
```

Not only can I `INSERT` the wrong datatype. I can also `SELECT` it.

I have tried `PRAGMA strict=ON;` and `PRAGMA strict=1;`. Neither works. I think I did not correctly enable strict mode.

How do I correctly enable strict mode?

Comment: `This page is intended to collect ideas for new error conditions that would be enforced in strict mode, assuming that strict mode is someday implemented.`. in other words, this never actually happened

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/stricttables.html), you add `STRICT` to the end of the table declaration:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.37.0 2021-11-27 14:13:22
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE yay ( col1 TEXT, col2 INT ) STRICT;
sqlite> INSERT INTO yay ( col1, col2 ) VALUES ("this works", "this is the wrong type");
Error: stepping, cannot store TEXT value in INT column yay.col2 (19)
```

It should be noted, this is a new feature with SQLite version 3.37.0.  On any previous version of SQLite, the table creation will fail.  And any previous version will fail to open a database file created with this flag with a "malformed database schema" error, unless you specify the `PRAGMA writable_schema=ON` pragma before opening the database.

You can use a similar concept of [CHECK constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#check_constraints) on older versions of SQLite:

```
SQLite version 3.31.0 2020-01-22 18:38:59
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> CREATE TABLE yay ( col1 TEXT CHECK (typeof(Col1) = 'text'), col2 INT CHECK (typeof(Col2) = 'integer'));
sqlite> INSERT INTO yay ( col1, col2 ) VALUES ("this works", "this is the wrong type");
Error: CHECK constraint failed: yay
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation STRICT tables are only supported in 3.37 or newer versions of sqlite3