sqlite: CAST("not a number", NUMERIC) = TEXT?
Recently I wanted to find out for myself whether pydantic is that useful with combination with sqlalchemy or not, so I made a dull & dumb example:
from dataclasses import dataclass

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker

# SQLAlchemy setup
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


# SQLAlchemy model
class UserORM(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


# Dataclass
@dataclass
class UserDataclass:
    name: str
    age: int


# Pydantic model
class UserPydantic(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


# Example usage
def main():
    # 1. Dataclass example (doesn't throw error with wrong type)
    try:
        user_dataclass = UserDataclass(name="Alice", age="not an integer")
        print("Dataclass created:", user_dataclass)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Dataclass error:", e)

    # 2. Pydantic example (throws error with wrong type)
    try:
        user_pydantic = UserPydantic(name="Bob", age="not an integer")
        print("Pydantic model created:", user_pydantic)
    except ValidationError as e:
        print("Pydantic validation error:", e)

    # 3. SQLAlchemy example (dataclass accepts wrong type, but SQLAlchemy fails)
    session = Session()
    try:
        user_dataclass = UserDataclass(name="Charlie", age="not an integer")
        user_orm = UserORM(name=user_dataclass.name, age=user_dataclass.age)
        session.add(user_orm)
        session.commit()
        print("User added to database")

        user = session.query(UserORM).first()
        print("User from database:", user.__dict__)
    except Exception as e:
        print("SQLAlchemy error:", e)
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

What I actually tried to proof, is that passing data of wrong type to SQLAlchemy will make it throw OperationalError (in my case - sqlite3.OperationalError), but that's what i got:
Dataclass created: UserDataclass(name='Alice', age='not an integer')
Pydantic validation error: 1 validation error for UserPydantic
age
  Input should be a valid integer, unable to parse string as an integer [type=int_parsing, input_value='not an integer', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/v/int_parsing
User added to database
User from database: {'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x0000018FD26B0F50>, 'id': 1, 'name': 'Charlie', 'age': 'not an integer'}

Yes, I'm aware of oddly specific type affinity in sqlite as described here. In particular, official doc says:

A column with NUMERIC affinity may contain values using all five storage classes. When text data is inserted into a NUMERIC column, the storage class of the text is converted to INTEGER or REAL (in order of preference) if the text is a well-formed integer or real literal, respectively. <..> If the TEXT value is not a well-formed integer or real literal, then the value is stored as TEXT.

So, instead of asking whether SQLAlchemy hasn't failed with error as desccribed above, I would like to set a better question:
How come type affinity of malformed string that should be a integer, is actually a TEXT AND is accepted by SQLite? Why doesn't it throw error if it's clear that the string is not a number of any type?

python: 3.11.7,
sqlalchemy: 2.0.30,
sqlite: 3.45.1


related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70305278/2144390

@GordThompson thanks, that answers question #2, but not #1.
